# Invalid_Client error when trying to get a token

Tags: acumatica

We use  https://[tenant].acumatica.com/identity/connect/authorize to get an authorization code which works fine then we call 
**https://[tenant].acumatica.com/identity/connect/token** 
endpoint with below params:   
grant_type: authorization_code 
client_id: [client id] 
client_secret: [client secret] 
code: (the value from "code" query parameter from the first request respomse) 
redirect_uri: https://[local].ngrok.io/accumatica/access-token 

We get a bad request with error message:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

What could be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most common explanation is that `Client ID` and `Client Secret` values passed by the OAuth client don't match the `Client ID` and `Client Secret` values configured in the OAuth server (Acumatica).

Comment: I changed and refreshed the client secret, double checked client id and made sure it is correct. Still getting the error - what else could be the reason? We logged in to a tenant and created the client - not sure if that tenant needs some sort of authorization to be able to call these endpoints - because it is not the production tenant

Comment: Maybe missing information in headers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you're still having this issue - but perhaps it would be best to use grant_type = password.
That is the method recommended in Acumatica training documentation and we have used it that way to successfully get a token.
Here is a screen shot of the parameters from Postman...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DluXZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Acumatica also requires you to have the correct OAuth2 flow selected when or selecting a client on the Connected Applications panel. In your case you need to select Resource Owner Password Credentials.